# How many pairs of consecutive integers?

Tags: combinatorics

### How many pairs of consecutive integers?

How many pairs of consecutive integers between and inclusive 1000 to 2000 is no carry required when the two integers added ?

for example: 1001+1002=1003 is a valid counting but 1078+1079 is not.

Comment: Can you explain slightly better your problem. I fear I don't get your point.

Comment: count the  pair of consecutive integers from 1000 to 2000 such that  adding these two no carry required. for example adding 1001 and 1002 is a valid pair but 1078 and 1079 is not. because adding these two integers carry is required, for  (9+8) and (7+7)   carry is required

Comment: I calculated with programming language, and it's 255

Comment: no , the answer is 156.

Comment: Is 1001+1002=1003 a valid counting ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the smaller of the two consecutive integers have the digits $1abc$ (the one's digit is $c$, the $10$'s digit is $b$, the $100$'s digit is $a$). There are several possibilities.

1) $c<9$, so the next integer is $1ab(c+1)$ (the one's digit is $c+1$, the $10$'s digit is $b$, the $100$'s digit is $a$). To add those two without any carries in the addition process we must have

$$0\le a<5,\ 0\le b<5,\ 0\le c<5$$

I'm sure you can count all those possibilities. I get $5^3=125$.

2) $c=9$ and $b<9$. Then the next integer is $1a(b+1)0$ (the one's digit is $0$, the $10$'s digit is $b+1$, the $100$'s digit is $a$). Here to get no carry we must have

$$0\le a<5,\ 0\le b<5,\ c=9$$

I'm also sure you can count all those possibilities. I get $5^2=25$.

3) $c=9,\ b=9$, and $a<9$. Then the next integer is $1(a+1)00$ (the one's digit is $0$, the $10$'s digit is $0$, the $100$'s digit is $a+1$). Here to get no carry we must have

$$0\le a<5,\ b=9,\ c=9$$

I'm also sure you can count all those possibilities. I get $5^1=5$.

4) $c=9,\ b=9,\ a=9$. Then the next integer is $2000$. Here to get no carry we must have

$$a=9,\ b=9,\ c=9$$

I'm also sure you can count all those possibilities. I get $5^0=1$.

Then add up the counts for those four cases. I get $125+25+5+1=156$.

This problem is small enough to be checkable. I made an Excel spreadsheet, checking all the numbers from $1000$ through $1999$ for the smaller of the two numbers, and I got the same answer of $156$. I also get that answer when I use the single-line Python code

```
print(sum(all(int(c) + int(d) < 10 for c, d in zip(str(n), str(n+1)))
          for n in range(1000, 2000)))
```

Comment: I got it clearly now. thanks @Rony Daulton

Comment: @Rory Daulton, I didn't understand point number (4). $1999+1=2000$ has carry overs, right?

Comment: @Supermario: You seem to misunderstand the question. The relevant question is whether the operation $1999+2000$ has carries, and it does not. Whether or not finding the next integer after $1999$ involves carries was not considered relevant by the original questioner.

Comment: Oooh, I got it! Thank you.